# How to add digital signature to pdf file generated through SSRS custom export option

Tags: reporting-services, digital-signature

I am working on custom export option for SSRS basically I want to create a digitally signed
pdf file generated through SSRS. Here is code which I wrote in Render method.
currently file created in pdf formate without digital signature.
How can I create digitally signed pdf file? generated through SSRS custom export option.
I use iTextSharp library for digital signature

```
    bool IRenderingExtension.Render(Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.Report report, NameValueCollection reportServerParameters, NameValueCollection deviceInfo, NameValueCollection clientCapabilities, ref System.Collections.Hashtable renderProperties, CreateAndRegisterStream createAndRegisterStream)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];

        pdfRenderer.Render(
            report,
            reportServerParameters,
            deviceInfo,
            clientCapabilities,
            ref renderProperties,
           new CreateAndRegisterStream(IntermediateCreateAndRegisterStream)
        );

        Stream outputStream = createAndRegisterStream(report.Name, "pdf", Encoding.UTF8, "application/pdf", true, StreamOper.CreateAndRegister);

        while (true)
        {
            int read = intermediateStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            if (read <= 0) break;
            outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);

        }

        intermediateStream.Close();
        intermediateStream = null;
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Which version of SSRS are you using?

Comment: Where is the code you are using to add the watermark? Have you read these articles: [PDF watermark/background Rendering Extension](http://www.broes.nl/2011/02/pdf-watermark-background-rendering-extension-for-ssrs-part-2/) (which applies to SSRS 2005) and [Zip Rendering Extension for SQL Server Reporting Services 2005/2008/2012](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/488883/Zip-Rendering-Extension-for-SQL-Server-Reporting-S) (which has information on how to migrate the code from the first article to SSRS 2012)

Comment: I read both articles its helpful but i want before export report I add digital signature so that report generated in custom format (I use PDF format) is digitally signed

Comment: Then the second link should help you. It's about zipping but you could add your signing action instead.